# I try to use BertForSequenceClassification for binary sentiment analysis task, but during the evaluating process, all the logits all the same

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

It seems all the things all right during the training process, and every 10 step i try to evaluate the model by using dev_data_set, the model give every the sample of the batch the same logits.

This is my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->

       def train(self):
        params = [{'params' : self.model.parameters()}]
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params, lr=self.args.lr, weight_decay=self.args.weight_decay)
        my_lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(optimizer=optimizer, gamma=self.args.decay_rate)
        best_eval_loss = 1e9
        for epoch in range(int(self.args.epochs)):
            total_train_loss = 0
            step = 0
            train_batch_num = 0
            for batch_index, batch in tqdm(enumerate(self.train_loader)):
                self.model.train()
                step += 1
                train_batch_num += 1
                # optimizer.zero_grad()
                sources = list(batch[0])
                label = batch[1]
            
                inputs = self.tokenizer(sources,return_tensors='pt', padding=True).to(self.device)
                labels = torch.tensor(label).to(self.device)
                labels = labels.squeeze(0)

                logits = self.model(**inputs, labels=labels).logits

                loss = self.model(**inputs, labels=labels).loss
                
                # logits = outputs.logits
                # loss = self.loss(logits , labels)

                # print('train loss per step:', loss.item())
                total_train_loss += loss.item()

                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                
            
                if step % 10 == 0:
                    total_dev_loss = 0
                    self.model.eval()
                    dev_num = 0
                    with torch.no_grad():
                        for batch_index, batch in tqdm(enumerate(self.dev_loader)):
                            sources = list(batch[0])
                            label = batch[1]
                            dev_num += 1
                            

                            inputs = self.tokenizer(sources,return_tensors='pt', padding=True).to(self.device)
                            labels = torch.tensor(label).to(self.device)
                            labels = labels.squeeze(0)

                            logits = self.model(**inputs, labels=labels).logits

                            loss = self.model(**inputs, labels=labels).loss
```

During the training process:
the logits are:
**training logits:  tensor([[-0.3385, -1.0671],
[-0.1526, -1.0956]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)** . It seems all right.

But after pass the line :  **if step % 10 == 0:**,
no matter what the data is, for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAVId.png)

or
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDdpz.png)
the eval logits become the same:

- eval logits:  tensor([[-0.4534, -0.9629],
  [-0.4533, -0.9628]], device='cuda:0')
- eval logits:  tensor([[-0.4534, -0.9629],
  [-0.4534, -0.9630]], device='cuda:0')